# PHP code on C++

Tags: php, c++

I would like to know how this code would look in C++:

```
<?php

$read=fread(fopen('cookie.txt', 'r'), filesize('cookie.txt'));


$pattern = "/[a-f0-9]{32}/";
preg_match($pattern, $read, $matches);
echo $matches[0];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `boost::regex`. The following is an example which may not be exact equivalent to your PHP code.I don't know PHP, so test it extensively before you use it. :-)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

std::ifstream file("cookie.txt");
std::stringstream input;
input << file.rdbuf();
file.close();

boost::regex pattern("/[a-f0-9]{32}/");
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
if(boost::regex_match(input.str(), results, pattern, boost::match_default |  boost::match_partial))
{
    //results contains the matches
}
```

Comment: boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
if(boost::regex_match(input.str(), results, pattern, boost::match_default |  boost::match_partial))
{
    //results contains the matches
}
 errors :S

Comment: @rammstein: what error? can you post the error? Also have you installed boost library on your machine?

Comment: this is a part of errors : mplementation<char>::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) const]+0x9a): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost9re_detail31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcE12error_stringENS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) const]+0x129): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1):

Navaz makes it look like reading a file in C++ is hard or requires pointers. Neither is the case. In fact, the file can be read in one line:

```
std::ifstream in("cookie.txt");
string str(static_cast<stringstream const&>(stringstream() << in.rdbuf()).str());
```

(This may look daunting but it’s conceptually simple. We read the file into a string stream and copy the result into a string `str`).

The rest of the solution would be identical.

Comment: I often forget to use this way to read files. :(.. +1 for reminding me this once again. :-)